# How to access url with custom route pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I have set my pattern to this:

```cs
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            //name: "default",
            //pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            name: "custom",
            pattern: "{company?}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
endpoints.MapRazorPages();
```

When I access the url vie browser like `https://localhost:44387/123/Users` the page will successfuly displayed and the value `123` successfully retrive in the controller:

```cs
public IActionResult Index(string company)
{
    //code here
}
```

How can I access this via razor? before the I updated the pattern, I only use the default like this code

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="123/Users" asp-action="Index">User</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Clients" asp-action="Index">Client</a>
</li>
```

I tried appending `123` to the `asp-controller` but it does not work.
What am I missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: Are `<li>` tags in your question is fragment of the `Index.cshtml` of the `Users` controller? If YES, just remove `123`:  use `asp-controller="Users"`.

Comment: @Jackdaw,if i remove that, nothings happens. page will just reload

Comment: But what you are expected to happen when you press on this link, with `asp-controller="123/Users" asp-action="Index"`? You are already in `Index` view of the controller `Users`. **_What is the good of it?_**

Comment: @Jackdaw, When user clicks that button it will proceed to like https://localhost:44387/123/Users, but 123 is just dummy data, planning to like some CompanyName after i find a solution, will display Users Index,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="\123\Users\Index">User</a> 
</li>
```

Or use the HTML helper method:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    @Html.ActionLink("Users", "Index", "Users", routeValues: new { company = "123" }, htmlAttributes: new { @class= "nav-link text-dark" })
</li>
```

For more information see [HtmlHelperLinkExtensions.ActionLink Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelperlinkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnetcore-6.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_HtmlHelperLinkExtensions_ActionLink_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_IHtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Object_)

Comment: hi sir it works but the url is different https://localhost:44387/Users?company=123

Comment: my bad sir, its works! i just forgot to to uncomment the custom code. thanks!